# React ref state is null

Tags: reactjs, components, state, ref

I want to access the state of a Child component by using refs, but the state of the ref is always null.

In my React app, I have an `Editor`(basically, it is a form) that manipulates its own states, e.g. value change, update. The editor is used on multiple pages.

**Editor.jsx**

```
    export default class Editor extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                value1: null,
                ... other values 
            };
         }

         onValue1Change = (e) => {
            this.setState({value1: e.target.value});
         }

         onSave = (e) => {
            // save values
         }

         render() {
             return (
                <div>
                    <input value={this.state.value1} onChange={this.onValue1Change}/>
                    ... other input fields
                    <button onClick={this.onSave}>Save</button>
                </div>
             )
         }
     }
```

Now, there is a `RegisterForm` which covers all fields in the Editor. I made a small change in the `Editor` to hide the Save button so I can use it in the `RegisterForm`:

**RegisterForm.jsx**

```
    export default class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                email: null,
                firstname: null,
                lastname: null
            };
            this.Editor = React.createRef();
        }

        onSave = (e) => {
            let childState = this.Editor.current.state;
            // childState is ALWAYS null!
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onEmailChange}/>
                    <input value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.onFirstnameChange}/>
                    <input value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.onLastnameChange}/>
                    ...
                    <Editor ref={this.Editor} showSave={false}/>
                    ...
                    <button onClick={this.onSave}>Save</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Turns out `this.Editor.current.state` is always null.

I have **two** questions.

1. Why `this.Editor.current.state` is null?
2. If I want to use props, how should I change my code? E.g. If I let `RegisterForm` pass props to Editor, I'd imagine something like this:

**Editor.jsx**

```
    export default class Editor extends React.Component {
         // same constructor
         onValue1Change = (e) => {
            this.setState({value1: e.target.value}, () => {
                if(this.props.onValue1Change) this.props.onValue1Change(e);
            });
         }
         // same render
     }
```

**RegisterForm.jsx**

```
     export default class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                email: null,
                firstname: null,
                lastname: null,
                value1: null,
            };
        }

        onValue1Change = (e) => {
            this.setState({value1: e.target.value});
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Editor showSave={false} onValue1Change={this.onValue1Change}/>
                    ...
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

does it make the Child component render twice? Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the ref as a prop to the `<Editor/>` component but not doing anything with it after that.

For example:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Receive props and ref through the `forwardRef()` callback parameter, then pass the ref to the child node.

This is called [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

I made a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ref-state-is-null-vo6qi) for you to test it!

Comment: Thanks, ref forwarding fixed the issue.